# Add extra information across cart/checkout/invoice in Ubercart

Tags: ubercart

I would like to add extra information in cart, checkout and invoice in Ubercart. Idea is to show discount ammount that was implemented by hook_uc_cart_alter - I want to add above the Total Price, Another value - Discount, and show that discount on all forms.

I can add extra values by appending in hook_tapir_table_alter, but i am not sure if this right way, or is it only for viewing purpouse? Is there other more reliable method ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there's no other module i know of that exposes this data. i too had to do hook alters to recalculate the total and discounts to have it show in the checkout forms.

Comment: Can you share bits of your code?